# How can I call a previous element inside a loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying something like this-

```
     for j in range(1,100):
     ej=[]
     rj=[]
     vj=[]
      for i in range(0,10):
       pj=(r(j-1)[i]+v(j-1)[i]*0.01)
       qj=v(j-1)[i]
       rj.insert(i,pj)
       vj.insert(i,qj)
      for i in range(0,10):
       z1=0.5*1*(vj[i]**2)
       ej.insert(i,z1)
       ejtotal=sum(ej)
       print(j,ejtotal)
```

Where i want the `j` loop to start from `1`, and I will give the value of `r0` and `v0` beforehand. But the part `r(j-1), v(j-1)` is not working, it cannot understand `(j-1)` and call the previous value of that object. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, indent your code correctly.

Comment: What isn't working? what error does it give? what output does it give? what output do you expect?

Comment: it says- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Softwares\Python\source\code(19-08).py", line 38, in <module>
    pj=(r(j-1)[i]+v(j-1)[i]*0.01)
NameError: name 'r' is not defined

Comment: It will help others (and maybe yourself) understand what you are trying to achieve a bit better if you [indent your code in a meaningful way](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have variables with numbers in them, such as `r0` and `v0`, and you're trying to look them up using a numerical calculation `r(j-1)`. This doesn't work, as Python interprets `r(j-1)` as an attempt to call a function `r` with the argument `j-1`. I suspect you'll also find that your `rj`, `vj` and `ej` values aren't doing what you expect (they're not writing to `r1`, `v1`, `e1` and so on, they're just names that end with "j").

You should instead use a list for the `r` values, and `append` the new values for each `j` value. Instead of `r0`, you'd look up `r[0]`. There will be no issue if you use `r[j-1]`.

I suspect you want something like:

```
r = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] # example r[0] data
v = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] # example v[0] data
e = [[]] # no e0 value is used

for j in range(1,100):
     r.append([r[j-1][i]+v[j-1][i]*0.01 for i in range(10)])
     v.append([v[j-1][i] for i in range(10)])
     e.append([0.5*1*(v[j][i]**2) for i in range(10)])
     ejtotal = sum(e[j])
     print(j,ejtotal)
```

I've simplified things a bit by replacing the inner loops by list comprehensions. You could reduce it quite a bit more by using the index `-1` to refer to the last item in a sequence, and perhaps iterating directly over the values in the preceeding list rather than indexing them. You could also just reuse the first `v` and `e` values, since they do not change with increasing `j` values.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I was taking it wrong. It was not considering it as r1, r2 etc. But your code also is not working somehow, its saying "list index out of range" in line 6.

Comment: Oh, oops, I only put 9 values in my example `r[0]` lists, instead of the intended 10. It should work now.

Comment: Yeah, its working, thank you very much... But can you please tell me if instead of using your list comprehension method I go for the old looping system I did previously(I have taken care of r[j] problem according to your solution) it still not working. why?

Comment: @RAJARSHIBANERJEE: Without seeing updated code and details about what "not working" means I couldn't guess.